# Flutter putting Image.network into Dart isolate

Tags: flutter, dart

Here i have a simple class that i show images from network with `Image.network`. as i used this class into a `Listview`, during scrolling that cause of a bit lag and i think i can fix it with `Isolate`.

after reading some documentation about this feature in `Dart` i'm not sure how can i put this this class or part of that such as a simple widget into that.

```dart
class InistaLikers extends HookWidget {
  final List<String> imageUrls;

  const InistaLikers({required this.imageUrls});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late double _width = 0;
    late int count = 4;
    final _orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    final _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    useEffect((){
      if(_orientation == Orientation.portrait){
        _width =  _screenWidth* 0.39;
        count = 4;
      }else if(_orientation == Orientation.landscape){
        _width = (_screenWidth / 2) * 0.39;
        count = 3;
      }
    });

    return Container(
      width: _width,
      height: 35.0,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: List.generate(
                count,
                    (i) {
                  return Positioned(
                    right: imageUrls.length + (20.0 * i),
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 35,
                        height: 35,
                        child: Image.network(
                          imageUrls[i],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              width: 35,
              height: 35,
              child: Image.network(
                imageUrls.last,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build a widget through an isolate as `dart:ui` which is used to render your widgets is only available on the main isolate. Moreover, `Image.network` already uses an `ImageStream` to manage the recuperation of an online image.

If you have some performance issues you should try to optimize the way you are building your widgets, for example if it was not the case already you should use `ListView.builder` if you have a lot of widgets to render.

You can find some ["Performance best practices" documentation on the flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices) or the article [Flutter Performance Tips written by Hasan Basri Bayat](https://itnext.io/flutter-performance-tips-4580b2491da8).

Here's some of the tips described in this article which you can apply to improve the performances of your app:

- Use Widgets Over Functions

```dart
// Don't do this
[
  _buildHeaderWidget(),
  _buildMainWidget(context),
  _buildFooterWidget(),
]

// Do this
[
  HeaderWidget(),
  MainWidget(),
  FooterWidget(),
]
```

- Use const where possible

```dart
const _myFixedHeight = 48.0;
```

- Use const constructors whenever possible

```dart
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

- Use nil instead of `Container()`

```dart
// Don't do this
Column(
  children: [
    text != null ? Text(text) : Container(),
  ],
)


// Do this
Column(
  children: [
    if (text != null)
      Text(text),
  ],
)
```

And you'll find some more tips in the article.